# How detected Backspace Appcelerator Android in textField

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

How to detect `Backspace` in Appcelerator on Android inside a `TextField`?
The events `change` and `keypressed` don't work.

```
var text_phone_1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
      top: 40,
      left: '22.5%',
      width: '10%',
      returnKeyType: Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
      keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD,
      hintText: '●',
      textAlign: 'center',
      maxLength: 1,
});
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2):

Use the "change" event and compare the textfield.value. If it is smaller than the old value the user removed something:

```
var text_phone_1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    top: 40,
    left: '22.5%',
    width: '100%',
    returnKeyType: Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    keyboardType: Titanium.UI.KEYBOARD_PHONE_PAD,
    hintText: '●',
    textAlign: Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER,
    maxLength: 100,
});

var oldText = text_phone_1.value;

text_phone_1.addEventListener("change",function(e){
    var lessText = (text_phone_1.value.length < oldText.length);
    oldText = text_phone_1.value;
    if (lessText) {
        alert("Backspace");
    }
})
```